# wrap numbers with double quotes

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i have a file with below sample data, and i am trying to wrap numbers only with double quotes. But i need to do this for numbers, numbers with + prefix, but not the numbers with Alphabets.

file.txt

```
- apple_docue:
     lp_from: +91
     lp_toNum: 041
     lp_realm: Madci99
```

i have tried below `sed` but it results like +"91", and Madci"99". i want to put those numbers with +prefix in quotes, but not the ones started with alphabets.

`sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\},\?$/"&/g' | sed '/[0-9]\{1,\}$/s/[0-9]\{1,\}/&"/g' file.txt`

`failed result:`

```
- apple_docue:
     lp_from: +"91"
     lp_toNum: "041"
     lp_realm: Madci"99"
```

But this not expected output for me.

expected output:

```
- apple_docue:
     lp_from: "+91"
     lp_toNum: "041"
     lp_realm: Madci99
```

please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([[:blank:]])([-+]?[0-9]+)/\1"\2"/' file
```

```
- apple_docue:
     lp_from: "+91"
     lp_toNum: "041"
     lp_realm: Madci99
```

**Alternatively**, you may use awk to do a numeric check on last field and wrap with the quotes accordingly:

```
awk '$NF == $NF+0 { sub($NF "$", "\"" $NF "\"") } 1' file
```

```
- apple_docue:
     lp_from: "+91"
     lp_toNum: "041"
     lp_realm: Madci99
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** As per @anubhava sir's comment in case a last field has `"` in its value to take care of this edge case one could try:

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
{
  spaces=""
  match($0,/^ +/);
  spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $NF=$NF!~/[a-zA-Z]/?s1 $NF s1:$NF
  gsub(/^\"+|\"+$/,"\"")
  $0=spaces $0
}
1
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, this will take care of spacing in lines too.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '{val="";val=$NF!~/[a-zA-Z]/?s1 $NF s1:$NF;sub($NF"$",val)} 1' Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution here.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
{
  val=""
  val=$NF!~/[a-zA-Z]/?s1 $NF s1:$NF
  sub($NF"$",val)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation above.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '                         ##Starting awk program from here and setting variable s1 as " value here.
{
  val=""                                 ##Nullifying value of val here.
  val=$NF!~/[a-zA-Z]/?s1 $NF s1:$NF      ##Checking if last field is having alphabets then keep it as it is OR add " to before and after its value.
  sub($NF"$",val)                        ##Substituting last column value with variable val value here.
}
1                                        ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: If input is `"12345 abc 12"` then it will make it `"12"345 abc 12`

Comment: @anubhava, Hi sir, added EDIT solution, kindly do lemme know your views here sir.